# How to use Extension in Frontend?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

i had installed a  Extension called

> yotpo review extension

and the extension installed successfully in backend. but i dont know how to bring this extension in frontend for every products as **STAR REVIEW.** kindly help me out here.

Comment: Did you check the configuration section?
Please check there, you might need to enable the module to make it work in front-end.

Comment: did you added api key in admin from yotpo?? I have installed this before for my client and its working fine.

Comment: already my extension is in a status "enabled"